# Batch Parse Filename to CSV

Tags: file, csv, batch-file, cmd

I have a folder of 9000 files named XX-randomString-numbers.jpg, where XX is an ID number I need.

I need to export it to a CSV list of [ XX | filename.jpg ] so that I can work with it in SQL.

So far, I have pieced this together:

```
Setlocal Enabledelayedexpansion
for %%A in ("C:\...\imageImport\*.jpg")
    do (
    set "str=%%~nA"
        for /f "delims=-" %%a in ("%str%")
            do set part=%%a
            echo.%part%
)
```

Comment: Windows 7. i will comment in what i have so far.

Comment: `cd "C:\...\imageImport\" & (for /F "tokens=1* delims=-" %%a in ('dir /B *.jpg') do echo %%a^|%%a-%%b) > output.csv`

Comment: You know what "**C**SV" means, don't you??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Echo off
Setlocal Enabledelayedexpansion
( Echo ID^|Filename
  for %%F in ("C:\...\imageImport\*.jpg"
  ) do for /f "delims=-" %%I in ("%%F"
  ) do set Echo %%I^|%%F
) >Out.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

You are enabling [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) but you are not using it. Anyway, you do not need it in your code, because you do not really need any interim variables. What you do need though is to correct the syntax of the [`for` loops](http://ss64.com/nt/for.html) and remove the superfluous line-breaks in front of `do`.

So here is the fixed code:

```cmd
for %%A in ("C:\...\imageImport\*.jpg") do (
    for /F "delims=- eol=-" %%a in ("%%~nA") do (
        echo(%%a^|%%~nA
    )
)
```

To write the result into a file `output.csv`, use this:

```cmd
@echo off
> "output.csv" (
    for %%A in ("C:\...\imageImport\*.jpg") do (
        for /F "delims=- eol=-" %%a in ("%%~nA") do (
            echo(%%a^|%%~nA
        )
    )
)
```

The `eol=-` option is specified for the `for /F` loop not to ignore files beginning with the default `eol` character `;` and so, the `eol` option is effectively deactivated, because `eol` becomes hidden behind `delims` as the same character is given.